# Convertir campo TIMESTAMP a hora

Tags: mysql

Tengo un campo `TIMESTAMP` en un campo de una tabla en MySQL.

**TimeStamp**

```
7/31/2018 5:58
7/31/2018 5:58
7/31/2018 5:57
7/31/2018 5:57
7/31/2018 5:55
```

Sé cómo formatear el campo para poder separar las fechas y el tiempo en Horas, Minutos y Segundos. Pero necesito convertir esos tres campos a horas.

La operación es como la siguiente:

```
Hora + (Minutos/60) + (Segundos/3600) = Horas
```

¿Cómo puedo llevar esto a MySQL? Ya sea con los tres campos formateados previamente o directamente desde el campo `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: ¿Podrías detallar qué tipo de dato contiene el campo y con qué SQL obtienes esos valores?

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que necesitas es calcular el número de horas (en coma flotante) desde las '00:00:00' del día, entonces la función que buscas es:

```
SELECT
  *,
  TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(fecha)) / 3600 horas
FROM tabla
```

Para calcular los segundos transcurridos desde las '00:00:00' uso [`TIME_TO_SEC()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) y para obtener únicamente la parte de tiempo (hora, minutos y segundos) uso [`TIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time).

Puedes ver un [ejemplo de funcionamiento en línea aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20c4f7a/2):

```
fecha                  horas
 2018-07-31 05:58:00    5.9667
 2018-07-31 05:58:00    5.9667
 2018-07-31 05:57:00    5.95
 2018-07-31 05:57:00    5.95
 2018-07-31 05:55:00    5.9167
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no me hacen sentido los resultados obtenidos en lapis y papel y lo que me arroja el resultado de MySQL.
TIME_TO_SEC(Time(Timestamp))/3600 as HrsSum2
Me da como resultado: 0.0006
Tomando como tiempo:
12:08:06 am
Resultado en lapis y papel, 12.135
Pienso que tiene que ver con formatear el resultado, pero no se como hacerlo.
@OscarGarcia

Comment: Dime qué valores son los que no coinciden. A mí sí que me coinciden. `5 + (57 / 60) + (0 / 3600)= 5.95`, por ejemplo.

Comment: Ahora que leo detenidamente tu comentario me asalta una duda: ¿estás usando un campo `TIMESTAMP` o estás usando un campo `INT` que almacena un timestamp de unix?

Comment: En si pienso que es in campo Timtamp ya que contiene los datos así:
8/7/2018  5:59:59 AM
Y digo pienso, porque no tengo el acceso directo a las tablas si no a vistas que creo el provedor de la aplicación y con ellas podemos realizar algunas consultas.
@OscarGarcia

Comment: Un campo `TIMESTAMP` no tiene ese formato, además de que guarda la información en UTC y en formato de 24h. Parece que esa vista te entrega una cadena de caracteres formateada a partir de un campo `TIMESTAMP`. ¿El proveedor de la aplicación puede entregarte el campo real? Si no es así agradecería que mostraras datos reales en la pregunta para hacerte el código mejor. En la pregunta no aparecía por ningún lado AM o PM como en tu comentario.

Comment: Este es un resultado del campo Timestamp.
[IMG]http://i63.tinypic.com/2qstcom.jpg[/IMG]
@OscarGarcia

Comment: En ese enlace (quitando las etiquetas [IMG]) no veo nada. ¿Podrías copiar/pegar en la pregunta?

Comment: Perdon a ver así:
2018-08-14 21:22:14
2018-08-14 21:22:21
2018-08-14 21:23:34
2018-08-14 21:23:49
2018-08-14 21:23:49
2018-08-14 21:24:13
2018-08-14 21:24:51
2018-08-14 21:26:39
2018-08-14 21:26:39
2018-08-14 21:28:26
2018-08-14 21:28:26
2018-08-14 21:28:43
2018-08-14 21:28:43

@OscarGarcia

Comment: Entonces es el formato normal, debería funcionar la función que te proporcioné. Voy a intentar agregarte al chat por si podemos continuar por ahí el intercambio de información y hacer pruebas de manera más fluida. [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83146/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-jose-daniel-solis).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función DATE_FORMAT() para convertir el TimeStamp al formato que deseas. Luego puedes aplicar las operaciones que quieras. Si consideramos que la tabla en la que tienes almacenados los datos se llama "tabla" y la columna en la que guardas tu TimeStamp se llama "TimeStampValue", quedaría así la query:

```
SELECT 
       DATE_FORMAT(TimeStampValue, "%h") + DATE_FORMAT(TimeStampValue, "%i")*60 + DATE_FORMAT(TimeStampValue, "%s")*3600 AS HorasSum
      ,DATE_FORMAT(TimeStampValue, "%d/%m/%Y") AS fecha
FROM tabla
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no me hacen sentido los resultados obtenidos en lapiz y papel y lo que me arroja el resultado de MySQL.
Date_Format(Timestamp,"%h") + Date_Format(Timestamp,"%i") / 60 + Date_Format(Timestamp,"%S")/3600 as HrsSum1
Me da como resultado: 12.0006
Tomando como tiempo:
12:08:06 am
Resultado en lapiz y papel, 12.135
Al igual que la sugerencia anterior el resultado deberia de ser 12.135 hrs.
@Javier

Comment: Viendo tu comentario a la respuesta de @OscarGarcia, por favor, reformatea la pregunta con los valores correctos.

Comment: Pude solucionar el problema, convirtiendo individualmente cada uno de los campos a hora.
Despues de eso realice la sumatoria de los tiempor y ya me da la suma correcta de los valores. Tanto en lapiz y papel como en el Query.

Gracias por su ayuda, como se cierra el tema?

DS